# Probabilities of same number occurrence in choosing two set of integers

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> $A$ has a set of integers, $\{1, \ldots , 1000\}$.
>
> $B$ has another set of integers (identical to $A$'s), $\{1, \ldots , 1000\}$.
>
> A draws randomly $50$ integers from $A$'s set **without replacement**.
>
> B draws randomly $100$ integers from $B$'s set **without replacement**.
>
> What is the probabilities that A and B have $1,2,\ldots,49,50$ same number(s) respectively?

I feel this problem is somewhat related to hypergeometric distribution, but have no idea how to fit it into this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the number of numbers that A and B have in common. The distribution of $X$ is indeed hypergeometric.

Imagine (it makes no difference) that A draws her numbers first.
Call the $50$ numbers drawn by A *good*. We want the probability that $X=k$. So we want the probability that among B's numbers, there are exactly $k$ good, and therefore $100-k$ bad.

There are $\binom{1000}{100}$ equally likely choices for B. There are $\binom{50}{k}\binom{950}{100-k}$ choices in which $k$ are good and $100-k$ are bad. Divide.

Answer (score 0):

There are $A = \binom{1000}{50}\cdot\binom{1000}{100}$ combination.
Number of desired combinations $A_k= \binom{1000}{k}\cdot\binom{1000-k}{50-k}\cdot\binom{1000-k}{100-k}$.

So the probabilities are $A_k/A$.